# PHP array loop to build ul li menu

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, foreach

I have an arraylist and I want to list it as a menu:

- If the `item['parent']` empty,  it will be parent item.
- If the `item['parent']` equal to `item['id']` it will be sub item to this

**The array that i want to list:**

```
$arr = array(
    [
        "name"   => "cat1",
        "id"     => "1",
        "parent" => "",
    ],
    [
        "name"   => "cat2",
        "id"     => "2",
        "parent" => "",
    ],
    [
        "name"   => "subcat1",
        "id"     => "6",
        "parent" => "1",
    ],
    [
        "name"   => "subcat2",
        "id"     => "6",
        "parent" => "2",
    ],
);
```

**and my php code:**

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (!$item["parent"]) {
        $id = $item["id"];
        echo "<li>";
        echo $item["name"];
    }
    if ($item["parent"] == $id) {
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>";
        echo $item["name"];
        echo "</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your nesting is only one level deep, you can use this code to find all the parents, then iterate over them and display all their children as a sub-list.

```
$parents = array_filter($arr, function ($item) { return !$item['parent'];});
echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    echo "<li>{$parent['name']}</li>\n";
    // find the children
    $children = array_filter($arr, function ($item) use ($parent) { return $item['parent'] == $parent['id']; });
    if (!empty($children)) {
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            echo "<li>{$child['name']}</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
<ul>
<li>cat1</li>
<ul>
<li>subcat1</li>
</ul>
<li>cat2</li>
<ul>
<li>subcat2</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

or as HTML:

- cat1
  - subcat1
- cat2
  - subcat2

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CSfkR)

If you can have nesting deeper than one level, you need to rewrite the above code as a recursive function:

```
function list_item($arr, $item) {
    echo "<li>{$item['name']}</li>\n";
    // find any children
    $children = array_filter($arr, function ($i) use ($item) { return $i['parent'] == $item['id']; });
    if (!empty($children)) {
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            list_item($arr, $child);
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}

$parents = array_filter($arr, function ($item) { return !$item['parent'];});
echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    list_item($arr, $parent);
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qOvd0)